# How can we delete a useless tag?

Tags: support, tags

I found some tags which are really useless and have one or two questions tagged, should we remove those tags? If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply remove them from all of the questions on which they appear.

After about a day, the system will automatically purge any tags that don't appear on any questions.